# Using Normal Transformation on a group of objects in Object mode in Blender 2.92

Tags: objects, transforms, object-mode

In V 2.83 I got used to selecting a group of objects (last selected=active) and then choosing Normal transformation in Object mode to be able to move the group along any axis of the Active object.

It was like a limited Local transformation for a selection group.

In V 2.92 it seems that I can no longer do that.

Is that the way of it? Is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After you selected the objects just press <kbd>G</kbd> and then twice the axis you wanna move.

E.g. <kbd>G</kbd> -> <kbd>Z</kbd> -> <kbd>Z</kbd> to move on local z-axis

Comment: ok, I'll try that but I learned that the behavior I described for transforming a group of objects in Object mode with transform set to Normal in any version< 2.92 can now be done in Gimbal transform orientation.

Select multiple objects. The last selected is, as always, the Active object. In Gimbal orientation the group will move along any axis on the Active object.